# Getting EditText to String

Tags: gettext

I'm kinda new here, so my question is simple as you can see...
This is my code in the onCreate():
    first_name_editText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
I've defined all the veriables. What's next? How do I convert the input into my variable?

Comment: What programming language? What technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the value of the edit text by this code:

```
String fname=first_name_editText.getText().toString();
```